# Асинхронно загрузить данные

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть личный кабинет, при входе отображается имя пользователя и в скобочках его балас(считается в 1с)
Как сделать чтобы баланс загружался после загрузки всей страницы т.к из-за этого страница грузится секунд 10

```html
<LoggedInTemplate >  
               <p>
             Здравствуйте, <a id="fio_hr" runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/profile.aspx" title="Manage your account">
               <%= Firstname %>(<% =Balance %>)<%--<asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" />--%>
                     </a>!
                                                            
                                                            
     <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Выход" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
       </p>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
```

где Balance это переменная которая вычесляется в другом коде написаном на c#

**Добавил 13.02.19**

сделал так, но код сыпитна на ошибку, в логах нет сообщения об ошибки а выводит object

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Account/GetBalance',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
    error: function (errorms) {

        console.log(errorms)
       
            },
            success: (json) => {
               
                console.log('-----')
                $('#balance').html(json)
            }
             })
```

GetBalanse

```js
string balance = WorkWithAct.GetSum1c1(cod1c, organiz_id);
                
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                
                Response.Write(balance);
                Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. На бэкэнде выделить отдельную  конечную точку, которая будет
   выдавать баланс.
2. Обращаться к ней (по AJAX) из JS в момент полной загрузки страницы.
3. Prfit!

Comment: Сделал как вы посоветовали, но чтото видимо не учел, и код не работает

Comment: Да, как ниже написали, вам надо тип text выставить и на фронте и на беке, для начала.

Answer (score 1):

Не стыкуются ожидаемый и получаемый типы данных. Что из себя представляет значение `string balance = ...`? Поставьте в `$.ajax`:

```
dataType: 'text',
```

Comment: balance получает сумму допустип balance ="400"

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛягаев Тем более. Это не JSON, а просто текст.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает